# Webcomic with adventurers finding a "We love you daddy, come back home soon" drawing in low-level enemy's backpack

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, order-of-the-stick

I am looking for a particular cartoon which, I am fairly sure, is from the *Order of the Stick* series -- but I've looked through the first 250 and I couldn't find it.

I am reasonably sure it's a webcomic, and probably *Order of the Stick*, but it could also be LFG or another *World of Warcraft*-related comic.

This is after the party kills several low-level enemies and, upon looting their corpses, find a crudely drawn picture which looks as if a child has made it. It shows a family of rats? goblins? which has "We love you daddy, come back home soon" written on it.

Comment: I am fairly sure this isn't from OotS, though it is a common idea that I've seen multiple variations on over the years.

Comment: Agree with @jwodder - I've re-read all OotS recently, and don't remember such a thing in it, but yeah, I think I do remember such a scene in another comic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to @jwodder's comment, I found it. They were right - the one I meant was not from *Order of the Stick* but [*The Noob* Comic](http://thenoobcomic.com/comic/25/) #25:

[image: adventurer finding a kid's drawing in a rat's wallet]

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept in 44 hours. And congratulations!

Comment: Geez. That's pretty brutal.